# Matlab extends graph in EPS export beyond limits

Tags: matlab, eps

I encountered strange behavior from Matlab when using the eps export. When I set up a figure like this:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
x = [duration([-3, 0, 0]), duration([-2, 0, 0]), duration([-1, 0, 0]), duration([0, 59, 59]), duration([1, 0, 0]), duration([2, 0, 0]), duration([3, 0, 0]), duration([3, 0, 1]), duration([5, 0, 0])];
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0];
plot(x,y)
set(gca,'XLim',[0 operationEnd-operationStart]);
xtickformat('hh:mm');
box off
subplot(2,1,2)
yyaxis left
plot(x,y)
yyaxis right
plot(x,y,'--');
set(gca,'XLim',[0 operationEnd-operationStart]);
xtickformat('hh:mm');

saveas(f,[PATH_SAVE,'eps_export_issue'],'eps2c');
```

The resulting figure looks in Matlab like this:

[image: Figure with yyaxis in Matlab]

However when I open the exported EPS in Inkscape it seems to ignore the set XLim if the figure and it looks like this:

[image: Figure with yyaxis exported to EPS]

The issue also occurs if I don't use `subplot` and don't use `duration` as this snippet:

```
x = [-3, -2, -1, 0.99, 1, 2, 3, 3.01, 5];
y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0];

f = figure();
yyaxis left
plot(x,y)
yyaxis right
plot(x,y,'--');
set(gca,'XLim',[0 4]);
box off

saveas(f,'eps_export_float','eps2c');
```

leads to an exported EPS that looks like this with the same issue:

[image: Float single plot EPS export]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I'd need to see the EPS file to comment, but this seems like its not really a question about EPS so much as a bug report for matlab.

Comment: Hi @KenS Mathworks just confirmed to me that this is a known bug. However the workaround they suggested is not an option as it results in a low resolution pixel graphic. I ended up slicing the data before plotting to resolve this issue.